# Mapping json object to Spring object in REST service

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST service defined in Spring as follows:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<String> addArticle(@RequestBody Article article){
      try{
         articleService.addArticle(article.getTitle(),
                                   article.getContent(),
                                   article.getTags(),
                                   article.getPublishStatus(),
                                   article.getCompanyId(),
                                   article.getCategory());
         return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
      } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
      }
   }
```

And my article is defined as follows:

```
public class Article {

   private int id;

   private String title;

   private String content;

   private String smsContent;

   public String getSmsContent()
{
    return smsContent;
}



public void setSmsContent(String smsContent)
{
    this.smsContent = smsContent;
}


private String[] tags;

   private int companyId;

   private String category;


   public String getCategory(){
      return category;
   }



   public void setCategory(String category){
      this.category = category;
   }


   private byte publishStatus;


   public String getTitle(){
      return title;
   }


   public void setTitle(String title){
      this.title = title;
   }


   public String getContent(){
      return content;
   }


   public void setContent(String content){
      this.content = content;
   }


   public String[] getTags(){
      return tags;
   }


   public void setTags(String[] tags){
      this.tags = tags;
   }


   public int getCompanyId(){
      return companyId;
   }


   public void setCompanyId(int companyId){
      this.companyId = companyId;
   }


   public byte getPublishStatus(){
      return publishStatus;
   }


   public void setPublishStatus(byte publishStatus){
      this.publishStatus = publishStatus;
   }



   public int getId(){
      return id;
   }



   public void setId(int id){
      this.id = id;
   }



}
```

How do I call this service using Angular? I tried following code:

```
function createArticle(name, companyId, title, content, tags, category) {
                var request = $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : '/inbound/api/article/create.json',
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    transformRequest : function(obj) {
                        var str = [];
                        for ( var p in obj)
                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "="
                                    + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                        return str.join("&");
                    },
                    data : {
                        title : title,
                        content : content,
                        tags : tags,
                        companyId : companyId,
                        category: category
                    }
                });
```

I am getting error `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with JSON, you need to set your form and handler accordingly.

REST handler

`@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")`

Angular

```
headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

you have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

just `/create`

**Second**

You have:

```
url : '/inbound/api/article/create.json',
```

Proceed to remove the `.json` that's the problem

**Third**

Be sure to indicate for the ajax event, the data you are sending is in JSON